# How to start to enforce Resharper rules in a large legacy application

Tags: c#, teamcity, resharper, code-analysis, legacy

We work on a large legacy application. The oldest code base is between 20 and 30 years old. Many developers have worked on it over the years and different architectures and programming styles were used.
Most code is C#, some C++ and very little VB6. My concern for this question is the C# code.

As a group of architects, we would like to clean up the code and make it more maintainable. We use ReSharper with Visual Studio 2013 (soon VS 2015). Some developers are keen on "making ReSharper happy" and have it show no warnings for a source code file, while others don't even use ReSharper or ignore any warnings signaled.
So we figured, the only way to have the whole team adhere to the same rules is to have it checked in the Continuous Integration build and fail if there are still ReSharper warnings.
That works very well on new solutions, but in legacy code it can show dozens if not hundreds of warnings in every class.
If we turn on all the rule checking on all files at once, our software would not build for month.

Fully automated code refactorings in ReSharper are dangerous in my experience because it can change the logic in some cases.

**Question 1:**
So how can one go about introducing the rule checking for a large legacy application?
We use TFS2013. I learned that Team City has a ReSharper plugin that allows to leave old code alone and only check what was modified in a check-in. Unfortunately we don't have the liberty to change our Build-Server. 

**Question 2:** But does anyone know how that Team City plugin works? 
**Question 3:** Are the entire files of changed classed checked, or just the lines that were touched? 
**Question 4:** How about rules that apply to the structure of the class (like the order of public, protected and private members)?

I would love to have something similar like the difference checking of the ReSharper Plugin for TeamCity for TFS, but I could not find anything. If you know of anything like that, let me know.

I would be happy to hear how any of you have mastered to introduce rule checking.

Comment: This is more easy to use http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/.

Comment: @Andreea Dumitru: I intend to use sonarlint once we switch to VS2015. But I never saw it as a replacement for ReSharper. Are you using ReSharper and Sonarlint or just Sonarlint?

Comment: Isn't a replacer for ReSharper, but you can apply specific rules more easily. I use both. ReSharper + SonarLite, without TeamCity. (Is the first time i heard about this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a description of what TeamCity allows you to do: [TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Detect+code+issues+in+a+build+using+ReSharper+and+TeamCity)

The important part concerning my question is this: TeamCity can be configured to compare the issues found per source file with the issues from the last build. If there are more issues of type warning or error, you can make the build fail.

To my knowledge, TFS does not have this capability and I am not aware of any add-ons that would accomplish something similar.

However, I believe that this difference issue checking is one of the most promising to improve legacy applications.